# Calculate area of apple from image

Tags: image-processing

I want to find area of following [apple](http://pngimg.com/upload/small/apple_PNG12438.png)

[image]

I want to do something like this:

define boundary region of  apple

`apple=...`

then find area using only `Area`

`Area[apple]`

like this

[image]

I tried first few steps :

```
Binarize[Import[
"http://pngimg.com/upload/small/apple_PNG12438.png"]] //ColorNegate
```

Comment: `Total[ImageData@Binarize@pic, 2]`?

Comment: @Kuba, `ImageDimensions[]` gives `{512,512}`, which gives a total area of $262144$, so I doubt that value which is about a third of total area, can be correct.

Comment: @Kuba In fact, the answer is $262144-93601=168543$, which is the same as `Length[Position[ImageData[c], 0]]`

Comment: @Feyre `Total[ImageData@Binarize@Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/4nyum.png"],
  2]` gives `168543`. I should have stressed out that I haven't used OP's code at all but it could have been deduced from the fact that I used Binarize.

Comment: Reminds me a similar [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2316192) on **Estimation of the total surface area in Indian elephants** winning the [IgNobel prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ig_Nobel_Prize_winners#2002) in mathematics in 2002.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `DominantColors` as follows.

```
im = Import["http://pngimg.com/upload/small/apple_PNG12438.png"];
res = DominantColors[im, Automatic, {"Count", "Color"}]
```

[image]

To be sure if the reddish color is indeed the **eatable** part of the apple check this.

```
eatable=DeleteSmallComponents@First@DominantColors[i, Automatic, "CoverageImage"]
```

[image]

Now the exact **eatable** part can be recovered as the first entry of the output.

```
DominantColors[eatable, Automatic, {"Count", "Color"}]
```

> {152709, 109435}

Now what the OP wanted!

```
positions = ImageValuePositions[ColorNegate@EdgeDetect@eatable, 0];
apple = Graphics[
   FilledCurve[Line[positions[[Last@FindShortestTour[positions]]]]]] //
   DiscretizeGraphics[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1] &
```

[image]

And we can get the area..

```
{Area[apple], NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] apple]}
```

> {152615.,152615.}

### But who eats a 2D apple..

But we can also make a 3D apple and calculate how much surface we need to **munch**.

```
pts = positions[[Last@FindShortestTour[positions]]];
par = BSplineFunction[ExponentialMovingAverage,TranslationTransform[-Mean@pts] /@ pts, .25],
SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 2];
ap = RevolutionPlot3D[{First@par[t], Last@par[t], t}, {t, 0, 1},RevolutionAxis -> {0, 1, 0},
PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 3,Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes->False];
appleColor = res[[1, 2]];
apple3D = DiscretizeGraphics[
  Cases[Normal@ap, _GraphicsGroup, -1][[1]],
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> 
     Directive[res[[1, 2]], Specularity[White, 20], 
      Glow[Darker[appleColor, .5]], Lighting -> "Neutral"],
    {1, All} -> Directive[Thin, Darker@res[[1, 2]]]}
  ]
```

[image]

And here goes the surface/munching area with some dimensional info..

```
{RegionDimension@apple3D,RegionEmbeddingDimension@apple3D,IntegerPart[RegionMeasure@apple3D]}
```

> {2, 3, **1450102**}